# Need to disable x-pack in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We are using Elastic, logstash and kibana with x-pack trial period, now that x-pack license is expired... How do I disable the x-pack license permanently.

In kibana, I am getting as below, How to avoid this alert.

```
Your trial license is expired
Contact your administrator or update your license directly.
```

We have add the configuration as below in elastic,kibana... but seems to be not working.

```sh
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

lastly Index management not able to view as license period has expired.

```sh
You do not have permissions to use Index Management
```

Any help is appreciated on above questions.

Comment: Which version of the stack are you using? In the last versions you need to set `xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic` in your `elasticsearch.yml` file for each node.

Comment: X-pack basic version is free. However, for older version of Elastic stack, you will have a raise a request to get a new key(no cost) or you can migrate to a newer version altogether.

Try https://license.elastic.co/registration/ if it solves your problem.